# What is this S icon inside white square?

Tags: applications, notification-icons, app-icons

Anybody who knows about this app please reply.
Phone is Vivo

[image]

Comment: Hi, please follow the given link to help you identify it.

Comment: It's in my granddad's phone. I can't access it. Concerned if any scam app has been installed accidentally.

Comment: Let someone who has access do the need. With millions of Android apps available, we can't identify every notification either, moreover from non-store apps.